# Iterating over divs with same ID and adding number

Tags: jquery, loops

I am trying to iterate over every div with the the id 'slide' and add a number to the end (e.g slide1, slide2, etc)

I have been able to have a series of classes added to each div, but I can only get the same code to rename the first slide, not the rest of them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#slide").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', "slide" + (i + 1));
 });
});​
```

and jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/YsvCe/1/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Change ids to class. Id must be unique.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use classes rather than ids for multiple elements.

```
<div class="slide">hello</div>

...

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slide").each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('id', "slide" + (i + 1));
    });
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QaB76/

Comment: thanks, this works but I need to use id's in this specific case

Comment: If you have several elements with the same id, then your page isn't valid HTML (and it could cause lots of problems).

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, this is a better and cleaner solution - thank you

Answer (score 13):

ID attributes must be unique, `id` selector as it should, only returns the first matched element:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("div[id^='slid']").attr('id', function(i) {
       return "slide" + ++i;
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YsvCe/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Elements must have a unique ID. the `each` function isn't iterating over the other divs. So find a way to select them all without violating that rule. The following works:

```
$("div").each(function(i)
```