# Why does the CSS element fail to show correctly when done dynamically (percentage bar)?

Tags: javascript, php, css, user-interface

My site shows users their results on a quiz. The results are returned from a SQL database.
I have confirmed that the data is being returned correctly and as the correct type (integer).
The text fields are being added as expected however for the percentage bar (user's score), only the first one loads correctly.

My  code in php file:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $width = $("#myResultBar").data('width');
    $("#myResultBar").css("width", $width + "%");
  });
  </script>
```

My  and <?php code that only does the first display with percentage bar correctly:

```
<?php
  for($i = 0; $i < count($life_ins_quiz_chapter_num); $i++){
?>
      <!-- results box -->
      <div class="result_box">
        <h3 class="hd text-center">Chapter: <?php echo $life_ins_quiz_chapter_num[$i];?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $life_ins_quiz_chapter_desc[$i];?></p>
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="bar_main col-sm-11 col-9">
            <div id="mySaving" class="bar">
              <div id="mySavingBar" data-width="<?php echo $life_ins_quiz_chapter_pct[$i];?>"></div><!--problem here-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="percent col-sm-1 col-3">
**            <!--This only shows up the first time. What am I doing wrong?-->**
            <?php echo $life_ins_quiz_chapter_pct[$i]; ?> %
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box_analysis">
          <h3>Question Score: <?php echo "[ " . $life_ins_quiz_chapter_score[$i] . "/6 ]"; ?> </h3>
          <?php //echo $saving_report_detail; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
<?php
  }//end for
?>
```

I have:
1-Done multiple checks to get the correct data type into that variable gettype(variable) = integer
2-Could not figure out if there was a way to change something in the js to have it increment the id
(for e.g. #MySavingBar_1(2,3)etc..

Open to any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: For the first record it is correct. Yes. This does not provide a solution for multiple values that will need to have their 'widths' input.

Answer (score 0):

***Adjust Code Accordingly***

When you are looping through PHP you have multiple `result_box`.
so inside the javascript, you need to loop through the `result_box` and set ht progrees `width`.

JS Explanation

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
/* find the `.bar` element inside the `result_box` 
   and loop through all the barElements
   find the `#mySavingBar` element inside the barElements
   get the `width` data property
   set the `width` to the element
*/
  $(".result_box .bar").each(function(index,barElement){
    var progressElement = $(barElement).find("#mySavingBar");
      var width = $(progressElement).data("width");
      $(progressElement).css("width", width + "%");
    });
});
```

```css
.bar > #mySavingBar{
  background-color:red;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Loop Here -->
<div class="result_box">
        <h3 class="hd text-center">Chapter: 1></h3>
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="bar_main col-sm-11 col-9">
            <div id="mySaving" class="bar">
              <div id="mySavingBar" data-width="20"></div><!--problem here-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- Loop End --->

<!-- dummy data -->
<div class="result_box">
        <h3 class="hd text-center">Chapter: 1></h3>
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="bar_main col-sm-11 col-9">
            <div id="mySaving" class="bar">
              <div id="mySavingBar" data-width="40"></div><!--problem here-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="result_box">
        <h3 class="hd text-center">Chapter: 1></h3>
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="bar_main col-sm-11 col-9">
            <div id="mySaving" class="bar">
              <div id="mySavingBar" data-width="50"></div><!--problem here-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- dummy end -->
```

Comment: If there is only 'one' <div class=result_box> that is being generated dynamically (based on number of rows in the database), can you help explain why you created other divs? Is it because you cannot call on a database here? What should I use as the index and the barElement in the jquery - function(index,barElement)? I am new to JQuery so got confused about these. The code snippet works here but not in my program (which only has one div)

Comment: where are you placing the `script` tag ? place `script` tag at bottom of the page...

Comment: I moved the script tag to the bottom (outside <body> </body>.  There was no difference. I am still working to try to  get your result. However the progress bar does not show at all when I am trying. At the moment the value is coming from a php array that i echo here: 
              <div id="mySavingBar" data-width="<?php echo $score[$index]; ?>"></div>
This only generates the bar 'once' with my current code. Zero times with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions from @Chandra Shekhar helped me resolve the issue.

In this case i used the jQuery [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function to iterate through each of the divs that were generated. I had to switch from using id="myResultBar" to a class, class="myResultBar".This was suggested by this answer [iterating over divs...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480365/iterating-over-divs-with-same-id-and-adding-number).
The code that resolved it:

```
    $(".myResultBar").each(function(i) {
         $width = $(this).data("width");
         $(this).css("width", $width + "%");
      });
```